# How to alter the message the user is seeing after 2 attempts

Tags: python, while-loop

I realize this question might be trivial for most users, but i am struggling to find the approach after hours of googling.

How to alter the message the user is seeing after 2 attempts? If the user types "right" twice, the message should be "Think harder! You are in the Lost Forest Go left or right?"

```py
n = input("You are in the Lost Forest Go left or right? ")
while n == "right" or n == "Right":
    n = input("You are in the Lost Forest Go left or right? ")
print("You got out of the Lost Forest! \o/")
```

Comment: you might store a variable for that which will reset to 0 whenever `variable > 1`

Answer (score 0):

Storing user progress will be useful

```py
go_right = 0 # 0 means that the user havent go to right

n = input("You are in the Lost Forest Go left or right? ")

while n == "right" or n == "Right":
    if n.lower() == "right":
        go_right += 1

    if go_right > 1: # If the user have go to right for 2 times, then...
        n = input("Think harder! You are in the Lost Forest Go left or right? ")
        go_right = 0 # Resets the variable
    else:
        n = input("You are in the Lost Forest Go left or right? ")

print("You got out of the Lost Forest! \o/")
```

Comment: Many Thanks Hanz. Looks very different vs. what I've expected but it works

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
msg = "You are in the Lost Forest Go left or right? "
msg2 = "Think harder! You are in the Lost Forest Go left or right? "
repeated = 0

n = input(msg).lower()
while n == "right":
    repeated += 1
    n = input(msg2 if repeated>=2 else msg).lower()
    if repeated >= 2: repeated = 0

print("You got out of the Lost Forest! \o/")
```

[Online demo](https://repl.it/repls/GratefulTealPerl)